# Python text extraction to Dictionary

Tags: python, regex

I'm new to coding can anyone help me to convert the below set of text to a dictionary using regex or any other technique.

`Bus Number: Departure` , will be common in all messages / blocks

```
KPN_Sleeper: Bus Number: Departure 
Bus code: Kpn-866489 KA-01-7233 Bangalore 
AC Sleeper/56 Seats
24 Seats booked 

SRS: Bus Number: Departure 
Bus code: SRS-5858 KA-31-5985 Bangalore 


SAM: Bus Number: Departure 
Bus code: SAM-0077 TN-23-0777 Chennai
```

```
{0:{
  "Bus_name": "KPN_Sleeper",
  "Bus code":"Kpn-866489",
  "Bus Number": "KA-01-7233",
  "Departure": "Bangalore",
  "others": "AC Sleeper/56 Seats 24 Seats booked "
},
1:{
  "Bus_name": "SRS",
  "Bus code":"SRS-5858",
  "Bus Number": "KA-31-5985",
  "Departure": "Bangalore",
  "others": ""
}}
```

Since I'm new to coding and regex, I'm feeling difficult to construct.

Comment: in the above text "Bus Number: Departure " are common and repeating words can we build any regex based on this?

Comment: It looks like you are looking to create a regex, but do not know where to get started. Please check [Reference - What does this regex mean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618) resource, it has plenty of hints. Also, refer to [Learning Regular Expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736) post for some basic regex info. Once you get some expression ready and still have issues with the solution, please edit the question with the latest details and we'll be glad to help you fix the problem.

Comment: It's a pity this question was closed so quickly, I'm not sure if we should
reduce this to a matter of finding the right regex. Solving this OP's problem
in a single, multiline, regex seems quite daunting (I tried, couldn't do it),
it's quite an advanced use of regexes. I was going to suggest pre-processing
the data to split the input data before looking for a (simpler) regex to parse
a single object, seems like a more helpful strategy for an OP new to coding and
regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your comment, I think you can try with this:

```
^(.*):\s*Bus Number: Departure\s*\nBus code:\s*([^ ]+)\s([^ ]+)\s([^\n]+)[ \t]*(?:\n|$)((?:[^\n]+(?:\n|$))+)?
```

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/d4U2wS/1)

Sample Code ([run here](https://ideone.com/bhQGpX) ):

```
regex = r"^(.*):\s*Bus Number: Departure\s*\nBus code:\s*([^ ]+)\s([^ ]+)\s([^\n]+)[ \t]*(?:\n|$)((?:[^\n]+(?:\n|$))+)?"

test_str = ("KPN_Sleeper: Bus Number: Departure \n"
    "Bus code: Kpn-866489 KA-01-7233 Bangalore dfdf\n"
    "AC Sleeper/56 Seats\n"
    "24 Seats booked \n\n"
    "SRS: Bus Number: Departure \n"
    "Bus code: SRS-5858 KA-31-5985 Bangalore dfdf dfd\n\n\n"
    "SAM: Bus Number: Departure \n"
    "Bus code: SAM-0077 TN-23-0777 Chennai \n"
    "asdfadf ;kasdjlfads;f lkadsjf")

matches = re.finditer(regex, test_str, re.MULTILINE)


for match in matches:
    print("Bus Name: "+match.group(1)+"Bus Code: "+match.group(2)+" Bus No: "+match.group(3)+" Departure: "+match.group(4))


#you can have other's value in match.group(5) , however, having it is conditional
```

Explanation:

1. `^(.*):\s* (.*)` --> First Capturing group to get Bus Name. `\s*` to cover empty spaces
2. `Bus Number: Departure\s*\n` -->  Bus Number: Departure  followed by blank spaces and a newline
3. `Bus code:\s*` The next line begin with Bus Code a colon and option blank spaces
4. `([^ ]+)\s([^ ]+)\s([^\n]+)[ \t]*`

   a) `([^ ]+)` --> bus code  \s --> blank space

   b) `([^ ]+)` --> bus number  \s--> blank space

   c) `([^\n]+)` --> Departure , It may have multiple word

   d) `[ \t]*`  --> it covers trailing spaces after departure
5. `(?:\n|$)` --> It covers the newline or end of string
6. `((?:[^\n]+(?:\n|$))+)?`

   a) `[^\n]+(?:\n|$` --> matches anything but newline followed by a newline or end of string

   b) `?:` makes it non capturing group

   c) `+` means there can be multiple lines

   d) the final `()`  sums all the `other` line in a group

   e) `?` makes this entire `other` process optional

Comment: thanks a lot @Rizwan M.Tuman.. this really helped me, thanks a lot for the  detailed explanation which will help me for future modification

Comment: I am glad that I could help you just before the question was closed :P

Comment: @DevDB you can check the sample code now

Comment: thanks alot @Rizwan M.Tuman , but we are not able capture the other section let me try that . thanks

Comment: match.group(5) covers other section. But other is optional. So, before you print group(5) you need to check if it exists or not... However you can send me sample string to investigate